# Marko Header and Footer Includes

Tags: express, partials, marko

I have two Marko components that I'd like to include in other components whenever they render on an Express server: `<main-header/>` and `<main-footer />`.

`components/main-header/index.marko` is as follows:

```
<lasso-page />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <lasso-head />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>...</nav>
```

And `components/main-footer/index.marko` is:

```
    <footer>...</footer>
    <lasso-body />
  </body>
</html>
```

The page I want to render on a certain route would look like:

```
<main-header />
    //component content
<main-footer />
```

However, I get an error of `Missing ending "body" tag` for `main-header`, so obviously this kind of EJS-partials like syntax isn't allowed. Is there a better way to do this without having a single `index.marko` file that is rendered in **every** route handler?

Comment: You can't split HTML like that as Marko expects the HTML syntax to be parseable (e.g. it's looking for the ending tag). When I get a moment I'll try and direct you to how includes work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the docs on using layouts:
https://markojs.com/docs/core-tags/#layouts-with-nested-attributes

The docs mention using `@tags` which allow passing named content chunks (if you wanted to put some stuff into `<head>` and other stuff into `<body>`), but if you only have a single content chunk to pass, you can use the default content.

You can create a layout that uses the `<include>` tag to render content passed to it:

```
<html>
<body>
    <include(input.renderBody)/>
</body>
</html>
```

Then use the layout, passing body content:

```
<custom-layout>
    Content goes here
</custom-layout>
```